# adding line items to a knockout observable array

Tags: knockout.js

Why does the quantity of each line item change to match the quantity of the most recently added item? I have an incomplete jsFiddle but it replicates my problem.(http://jsfiddle.net/jjfrick/cmwru2pv/105/)

```
    newLineItem: function () {
  if (viewModel.Quantity() >= 1) {
    var extPrice = viewModel.computedExtendedPrice().toFixed([4]);
    var pid = viewModel.selectedProduct().ProductID;
    var productData = [];
    productData = ko.utils.arrayFirst(viewModel.products(), function (p) {
      return p.ProductID === pid;
    });
    viewModel.getLineItems.push(new comboLineItem(viewModel.LineID, productData.Name, productData.Unit, viewModel.Quantity, productData.Price, extPrice, viewModel.FilledDate, viewModel.FilledBy));
  } else {
    alert("Please enter a quantity");
  }
},
```

Comment: your fiddle seems to be broken... no prices show

Answer (score 1):

Well since Quantity is an observable, judging by the initial if statement, and by the fact that you are using viewmodel.Quantity as a parameter to the combo constructotr you should do this

```
viewModel.getLineItems.push(new comboLineItem(viewModel.LineID, productData.Name, productData.Unit, viewModel.Quantity(), productData.Price, extPrice, viewModel.FilledDate, viewModel.FilledBy));
```

If you pass the observable directly then all of them would share the same reference to that same observable!

Recheck how the parameters are used by the constructor of comboLineItem, and evaluate all those observables to pass their value, if that is what you are looking to do

Comment: That was it. Thank you. I figured it was something simple.